We would have known when they came back. | Does this mean "We didn't know when they came back"?
A man is telling about how his brother drowned in the sea when they were both young, and how his parents pretended that he never existed. Here is a small part of the conversation:
TV presenter: When did your parents tell you what had happened and that in fact you gathered around the table and said "I'm so sorry but you know we don't have your brother anymore"
The man: Well we would have known when they came back from the hospital. ITV- my brother died  (see:2:35-2:50)
(then some more details ....) and then the man goes on to say (at 3:09-3:21):
"...my parents would have come back towards the end of the afternoon and told us that he was dead. So that's when we found out but I've discovered all these things later on and in the book it's that journey of discovery...
The structure "...would have known..." caught my attention, and has  driven me mad yet another time, because I can never quite be sure what it meant. Sometimes it acts like "simple past tense", sometimes "speculation about the past", but this one is confusing, because I can't understand whether he was sure of what he told about. Using "would have done" makes him sound he is not sure of the details he was telling about.
As far as I understand from the context, he means "we didn't know when they came back from the hospital", but then why "....would have known..."?
Similarly "...my parents would have come back towards the end of the afternoon.." Does he mean **"I am not sure but according to what I heard from X, they came back towards the end of the afternoon?

"Would have known," is ambiguous without context. For example:

We would have known of the storm, had we been home.
She would have known of a storm, since she was home.

In the first case, "had we been home," implies they had not been home, and had not found out about the storm until later.
In the second, the implication is that there was no storm, since she was home and did not witness it.
In the given sentence, the implication is that the guest is unsure of the timing, but likely would have been informed at the time his parents returned from hospital.

The OP hasn’t provided all the context directly in the question, but the video referenced by the OP is the complete context.

He says that his memory of the details is poor. So here, we would have known means essentially, “Though I don’t recall for sure, if I reconstruct events of the time from my perspective today, the most logical supposition is that we found out when they came back from the hospital.”
